# Google Cloud Datastore PropertyFilter Error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-datastore, google-php-sdk

I'm using the google apis php sdk and trying to access some data from my google cloud datastore. I'm authenticating no problem at this point, but am getting an error during my query. I pretty much look through the code in the sdk to implement it, since documentation is null, but there's nothing that hints at why i'm getting this error.

Here's my code:

```
    $run_query = new Google_Service_Datastore_RunQueryRequest;                                                                                                                 15  
    $query     = new Google_Service_Datastore_Query;
    $query->setKinds(array("views"));                                                                                                                  16  
    $query_filter = new Google_Service_Datastore_Filter;                                                                                                                       17  
    $query_property_filter = new Google_Service_Datastore_PropertyFilter;                                                                                                      18 
    $query_property_filter->setOperator('EQUAL');                                                                                                                              19  
    $query_property_ref    = new Google_Service_Datastore_PropertyReference;                                                                                                   20 
    $query_property_ref->setName('_IS_ACTIVE');                                                                                                                                21  
    $query_property_val    = new Google_Service_Datastore_Value;                                                                                                               22  
    $query_property_val->setBooleanValue(true);                                                                                                                                23 
    $query_property_filter->setProperty($query_property_ref);                                                                                                                  24 class Google_Model implements ArrayAccess
    $query_property_filter->setValue($query_property_val);                                                                                                                     25 {
    $query_filter->setPropertyFilter($query_property_filter);                                                                                                                  26   
    $query->setFilter($query_filter);                                                                                                                                          27    
    $run_query->setQuery($query);                                                                                                                                              28     null. 
                                                                                                                                                                               29   
    $views = $datastore->datasets->runQuery('my-project-id', $run_query);
```

Here's the error i'm getting:

`Google_Service_Exception [ 500 ]: Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/datastore/v1beta2/datasets/my-project-id/runQuery: (400) kind is required for filter: _IS_ACTIVE`

Where do I add this `kind` google is asking for??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I did need to use the `$query->setKinds()` method as Ed Davisson suggested, however it cannot just take a string. You need to give it the `Google_Service_Datastore_KindExpression` Object

Example:

```
$views_kind= new Google_Service_Datastore_KindExpression;
$views_kind->setName("views");
$query->setKinds(array($views_kind));
```

Comment: Argh, sorry about that, Eric. Thanks for posting the corrected answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Usually the library is quite easy to figure out what to do from reading the code. this was a bit more confusing than usual. I've also reviewed the json object that posts when I use the developer dashboard and that has helped me understand these query object in greater detail.

Answer (score 1):

Filters in Datastore queries typically require that you specify the kind of the entities you want to retrieve. Rather than passing it into the constructor, you can set it with:

```
$query->setKinds(array('views'))
```

Comment: I tried adding that and i'm still getting the error. updating sample to reflect changes in code.